# Unit tests with Rocket.rs

Tags: unit-testing, rust, rust-rocket

Im trying to write some unit tests for the 3 routes of my Rocket app. So far the `get index` function works fine but the two post requests arent working

Im getting confused because i keep getting a 404 request and i don't really know why

tests.rs:

```rust
use super::rocket;
use rocket::local::blocking::Client;
use rocket::http::Status;
use rocket::uri;

#[test]
fn index() {
    let client = Client::tracked(rocket()).expect("valid rocket instance");
    let response = client.get(uri!(super::index)).dispatch();
    assert_eq!(response.status(), Status::Ok);

}

#[test]
fn add() {
    let client = Client::tracked(rocket()).expect("valid rocket instance");
    let response = client.post(uri!(super::add))
        .body("note=This is a test")
        .dispatch();
    assert_eq!(response.status(), Status::Ok);
}

#[test]
fn delete() {
    let client = Client::tracked(rocket()).expect("valid rocket instance");
    let response = client.post(uri!(super::delete))
        .body("noteid=1")
        .dispatch();
    assert_eq!(response.status(), Status::Ok);
}
```

main.rs (some code omitted for space reasons):

```rust
#[cfg(test)] mod tests;

use curl::easy::{Easy, List};
use rocket::form::Form;
use rocket::response::content::RawHtml;
use rocket::response::Redirect;
use rocket::{response::content::RawCss, *};
use rocket_dyn_templates::tera;
use rusqlite::{Connection, Result};
use std::io::Read;

#[derive(FromForm)]
struct NoteForm {
    note: String,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Note {
    id: i32,
    note: String,
}

#[derive(FromForm)]
struct NoteID {
    noteid: i32,
}

#[get("/")]
fn index() -> RawHtml<String> {
    let mut html: String = r#"
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <h1>Rust Notebook</h1>
        <form method='POST' action='/add'>
        <label>Note: <input name='note' value=''></label>
        <button>Add</button>
        </form>
        <ul class='notes'>"#
        .to_owned();

    let notes = get_notes().unwrap();

    for note in notes {
        let noteid: String = note.id.to_string();
        html += "<li class='notes'>";
        html += &tera::escape_html(&note.note);
        html += "<form method='POST' action='/delete'> <button name='noteid' value='";
        html += &noteid;
        html += "' style='float: right;'>Delete</button></form></li>";
    }

    html += "</ul>";

    RawHtml(html)
}



#[post("/delete", data = "<noteid>")]
fn delete(noteid: Form<NoteID>) -> Redirect {
    let conn = Connection::open("notes.db").unwrap();
    conn.execute(
        "DELETE FROM notes WHERE rowid = ?",
        &[noteid.noteid.to_string().as_str()],
    )
    .unwrap();
    Redirect::to("/")
}

#[post("/add", data = "<note>")]
fn add(note: Form<NoteForm>) -> Redirect {
    let conn = Connection::open("notes.db").unwrap();
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO notes (note) VALUES (?)", &[note.note.as_str()])
        .unwrap();
    log_notes(&note.note.as_str());
    Redirect::to("/")
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    sqlite();
    rocket::build().mount("/", routes![index, add, serve_css, delete])
}
```

any help would be great :)

Comment: Rocket will return a 404 if the route cannot be found _or_ if the parsed types on the request do not match the parameters on a handler.

If you (temporarily) remove the `<note>` from the `add` route does the test start passing? If so then the data youre adding to the body in the test is not a valid `Form<NoteForm>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in more than just the endpoint. The Client struct's get method expects the entire url to be passed as a string, not just the endpoint. If you were trying to make a get request to the "apples" endpoint of a server running locally on port 8000 and save the resulting response in a variable named response, that request would look like this:

```
let response = client.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/apples").send().unwrap();
```

Then, to assert the status code was OK (200):

```
assert_eq!(response.status(), StatusCode::OK);
```

The reason you are getting 404 is because you are making requests to endpoints without a host, e.g. "/apples" instead of "http://127.0.0.1:8000" and because nothing is at that endpoint, a 404 is returned after timeout.